# HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: geoserver

We upgraded GeoServer 23.1 to the latest version, 2.24.1, and now we are getting this error. Why we are getting this error?

```
2024-03-06 14:25:04.507:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.52.v20230823; built: 2023-08-23T19:29:37.669Z; git: abdcda73818a1a2c705da276edb0bf6581e7997e; jvm 15.0.2+7-27
2024-03-06 14:25:04.526:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///opt/geoserver/geoserver_app/webapps/] at interval 1
2024-03-06 14:25:04.757:WARN:oejx.XmlParser:main: ERROR@null line:3 col:74 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 74; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Configure'.
2024-03-06 14:25:04.763:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@66982506{geoserver,/geoserver,file:///opt/geoserver/geoserver_app/webapps/geoserver/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/geoserver/geoserver_app/webapps/geoserver}
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Unable to parse: file:///opt/geoserver/geoserver_app/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure(EnvConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1931)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1881)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 74; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Configure'.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2132)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3078)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure(EnvConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1931)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1881)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
2024-03-06 14:25:04.774:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6f152006{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-03-06 14:25:04.774:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @726ms
```

Comment: It says `Cannot find the declaration of element 'Configure'. ... Unable to parse: file:///opt/geoserver/geoserver_app/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` at the top so best check if that file is intact.

Comment: Hi bugmenot123, 
thank you for the quick response; we created a new jetty-env.xml file to copy the content over to, and that didn't work. We also try copied the file from a now working version, and we got the same error. any thought

Comment: can the parser see the internet to fetch the schemas referenced in that file?